# How to change only the color of curly brace made by \underbrace but keep the content color remain unchanged?

Tags: math-mode, color

I have to set globally the color of every math to blue. However, if I need to annotate an expression by using `\underbrace`, the curly brace must be in black (for example).

The following are my MWE and its corresponding output in which I failed to accomplish my objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\everymath{\color{blue}}
\newcommand\HighlightedTerm[2]{%
        \color{black}%
        \underbrace{#1}_{\color{red}\text{#2 term}}%
}
\begin{document}
Consider an expression $2a^3b^2cd^7e-ab^2cde^3$. It has 2 terms as shown in the following,
\[
\HighlightedTerm{2a^3b^2cd^7e}{1st}\HighlightedTerm{-ab^2cde^3}{2nd}
\]
Do you understand?
\end{document}
```

Could you help me to realize my objective? Please don't advice me to use TikZ or PSTricks. :-)

Comment: Note: making every equation in blue is my strategy  to prevent someone from photocopying my book.

Comment: How exactly do you expect that strategy to prevent anyone from photocopying your book?

Comment: @trav1s: Text in blue is difficult to be copied. It is my experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\underbrace` uses the definition of `\upbracefill`. Both commands are defined in the file `fontmath.ltx`

The command `\upbracefill` is defined as follows and you can see it opens a new math-environment.

```
\def\upbracefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
```

So the easiest way will be the adding of a simple `\color{black}` to the default definition:

```
\def\upbracefill{$\color{black}\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
```

Here your MWE using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\everymath{\color{blue}}
\newcommand\HighlightedTerm[2]{%
        \color{black}%
        \underbrace{#1}_{\color{red}\text{#2 term}}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\upbracefill{$\color{black}\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatother
\begin{document}   
Consider an expression $2a^3b^2cd^7e-ab^2cde^3$. It has 2 terms as shown in the following,
\[
\HighlightedTerm{2a^3b^2cd^7e}{1st}\HighlightedTerm{-ab^2cde^3}{2nd}
\]
Do you understand?
\end{document}
```

[image]